# Inserting throgh temp table MUCH faster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, insert

I tried

```
insert into TABLE (<columns>)
    select <column> 
    from <simple query> -- simple query took about 2secs to run
```

This was supposed to insert about 600 000 records. WAS SLOW (30 minutes for about 10000 rows - checking storage value in table property through SQL Server Management Studio) so I killed it

Retried out of despair:

```
select <columns> 
into #tmpTable 
from <simple query>

insert into TABLE 
    select * from #a
```

Took 2 seconds..... too tired to think, its 2AM

Comment: How many total records are in your simple query and do you cast all datatype conversions in your initial insert query.....handling all data type inconsistencies instead of leaving it up to the compiler might address the issue.....but unless given more that <columns>  and <query> it might be hard to pinpoint although is it really worth pinpointing at this point if SELECT INTO ##TEMP is giving you the performance for which you are looking?

Comment: Although the insert into permanent table will be somewhat slower due to additional indexes, more logging, etc,. such a large difference suggests the insert query may been blocked by other concurrent activity against the table.

Comment: Dan makes a good point if you are going to SELECT INTO a temp table you probably would want to include WITH (NOLOCK) after each table......this will avoid deadlocks and concurrency but it will not provide the most accurate data; however, since I am still I the dark as to the exact nature of your <query> <table> <columns> I can not make a recommendation either way just a mention that this is a possibility to improve performance during table locking from other unrelated concurrent transactions on the same table.